# Obtener el promedio de una dataframe con NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Quiero obtener el promedio de una dataframe con NaN.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   -1  NaN 0   NaN NaN 0   NaN
3   -1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4570    -1  -1  1   NaN -1  NaN 1
4571    -1  1   1   0   -1  -1  1
4572    -1  1   0   1   -1  -1  1
4573    -1  -1  1   -1  -1  -1  1
4574    0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN
```

Intenté el siguiente codigo

```
df_features.mean(axis = 0, skipna = True)
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con lo que dices que te devuelve? ¿A que te devuelve una Serie vacía, o a que el tipo devuelto es una Serie? Si es lo primero es raro, a mi no me ocurre con el mismo ejemplo que tú has puesto. Si es lo segundo es normal. Estás pidiéndole el promedio por columnas, de modo que el resultado es un vector (una Serie), en la que el índice será el nombre de cada columna y el valor el correspondiente promedio. Por cierto, ignorar NaN significa no usarlos en absoluto. Si la columna tiene todo NaN salvo un valor, ese único valor sería la media.

Comment: No se entiende el promedio de que secuencia de valores quieres tomar? De todo el dataframe? De una sola columna? De una fila?

Answer (score -2):

Primero, trata de quitar los NAN antes de calcular el promedio con la funcion df.fillna(0). Eso completa los nulos con 0 y te sirve para el promedio.

Comment: Yo no recomendaría para nada quitar las `NA`, un `NA` significa "No hay valor", un `0` significa hay un valor y es `0`.

Comment: Mala recomendación pues reemplazar los NaN por 0 en un promedio te desplaza la media hacia ese numero en particular lo que puede ser fatal en ciertos casos, en especial si se usan números reales. Una mejor solución consiste en eliminar los NaN para que no cuenten en el total (np.dropnan), y si el arreglo son puros NaN pues tiene promedio indefinido.